# Can Managed Object Contexts in different threads (main/private queues) handle the same objects?

Tags: ios, multithreading, core-data, concurrency, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have an `NSManagedObjectContext` in the **main queue** (the default context provided in `AppDelegate`), and I create another `NSManagedObjectContext` in a **private queue** to request data updates to web services. I use the main context to fetch all the objects to be shown and managed throughout the app, and I use the private context to insert the new objects I receive from services to avoid blocking the UI and to also avoid "interfering" with the objects in the main context in case the user and/or the app are operating with them. Both contexts are "siblings", they are not parent and child. This is because I need to create all new objects to later know if some of them should be removed (a property of the objects indicates that).

The point is, I then have duplicated sets of objects, one in the main context and another in the private context. They should have different object IDs, but according to the logic of my app they are the "same" objects. If I have an `objectA` in the main context, and I receive that same `objectA` in the private context but with updated values, I need to replace `objectA` in main context with `objectA` in private context. But they theoretically have different `objectID`. My questions are:

1. Can I search `objectA` in main context, remove it from there, and use `objectWithID` to "transfer" `objectA` from private context to the main ? Having into account that main context is in main queue and the private is in a private queue.
2. Instead, should I remove `objectA` from main context, then save private context, and then fetch again `objectA` from main context?
3. Maybe I should handle this scenario in another way...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Merge policy singleton objects that define standard ways to handle conflicts during a save operation
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSMergePolicy_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/data/NSErrorMergePolicy

Comment: Thanks, but I suppose merge policies only work if you are working with objects with the same `objectID`, right? That is not my case, from the point of view of my logic, `objectA` in main context is the "same" `objectA` I create in private context, but from the point of view of Core Data they don't, they have different `objectID`...